# My Table of Contents shows itself on the entries. How can I get rid off it?

Tags: table-of-contents

While using the `\tableofcontents` function, the first entry is the page where it is located, as the pic shows. I tried to omit it with `\tableofcontents*{}`, also without the keys, but none of them worked. How can I get to do it?

[image: onten]

EDIT: My code is, basically, this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage[notlot]{tocbibind}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

{\parskip=0pt
\tableofcontents}
```

Comment: Most likely you are using the `memoir` class? Are there some additional `\addcontentsline` in your document? Or is `tocbibind` used?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\tableofcontents*` works in `memoir`, though the starred and unstarred commands are the opposite way round from the standard document classes

Comment: @alephzero: I know that `\tableofcontents*` works in `memoir` -- I did not claim something different, did I? As long there is not a single of code, the cause of the problems is unclear

Comment: I just uploaded the code. @ChristianHupfer yes, I'm using a `tocbibind`

Comment: @Julio: Add `nottoc` to the option list of `tocbibind`...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Is it different to `notlot` option? I just did it as you say but didn't work. If actually I omit `notlot` option, it works, but omits also a Table of Figures I'm using

Comment: Well, `nottoc` does what `notlof` and `notlot` do for the LoF and LoT. Of course, you still need `\tableofcontents*` then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: It works! I was having a syntax mistake. Thank you!